# PHP: Why isn't my count(); printing out my array?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm currently doing a populating/editing my DB using PHP on a webpage I'm going to build. I'm relatively new to PHP so please excuse my "greenhorn" knowledge. My DB connection works, however, I don't understand why my function "displaySQL" and then counting the quantity as an array is not generating anything on my webpage. There's no number displayed on the screen, I was going to have that value put inside an HTML table afterwards. My DB settings are also established for the parameter part (host, username, password). Thanks for any help.

```
class User{

var $conn;
function __construct($hostname,$username,$password){
    try{
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=pjj5",
        $username, $password);
        echo "Connected successfully <br>";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

}

//display all users information
function displaySQL(){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts";

    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute();
    $results = $q->fetchAll();
    return $results;
}

$db = new User($hostname,$username,$password);
$res = $db->displaySQL();
echo count($res);
```

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: I'll check it out, but for now I just want to start at a basic scale of understanding things myself.

Comment: @tadman Isn't writing an ORM an obvious beginner project?

Comment: What version of PHP is this meant to be? It looks like PHP4. Turn error reporting on at the top of your script by adding the following `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. Also you're not assigning `$conn` to an instance variable, so it won't be accessible in your `displaySql` function. There are other issues too.

Comment: `$conn` should be `$this->conn`. PHP is not C++, class properties cannot be accessed as normal variables.

Comment: @Barmar I'd agree *if* the person attempting this has already used a few so they know how they work in principle *and* in practice. There's a lot to understand before embarking on this journey, it's really not for the person who's still learning PHP fundamentals. An obvious beginner project is learning how Eloquent works, and once they've got a good grasp on that, try and make their own as an academic exercise.

Comment: @tadman Sorry, I forgot to put a smiley, it was a joke.

Comment: It may be advisable to look at the source code of existing ORMs to understand the programming concepts in PHP.

Comment: @Barmar Around here I can never tell. The PHP community has a worrying allergy to frameworks that's quite disturbing. At times I wonder why some don't write their own OS to avoid using someone else's code.

Comment: Barmar, put a smiley? Now *this* I have to see :-))

Comment: @tadman it is helpful to try to build your own ORM to understand why you shouldn't do so.

Comment: @serakfalcon That's a long, painful process that's best contained in an academic environment, not when you're actually trying to build a site.

Comment: @tadman I guess it depends if you're getting paid for it or just doing it as a hobby. I was assuming the latter but totally agree with you if it is a paid project. Although I'd hope that a newbie to php would be doing such things as a hobby :)

Answer (score 0):

To access a variable of an object within the object you need to use the syntax `$this->`.

This line:

```
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=pjj5",
        $username, $password);
```

and this line

```
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

should have `$this->conn` instead of `$conn`. In the first function you create the connection to a new `$conn` variable that is local in scope to the function only, which gets discarded after the object is constructed. For the function `displaySQL()`  `$conn` is undefined.